# Error in itemize environment

Tags: itemize

I keep getting the error "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. ^^I^^I\end{itemize}" for the following snippet and the pdf file is not shown in texstudio, but when I check the pdf file in the assigned directory, the corresponding snippet has been correctly generated. Could you please tell me what is the issue?

```
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Literal constants
        
        \item Declared constants
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \emph{const} keyword
        \end{itemize}
        
        \item Constant expressions
        \begin{itemize}
            \emph{constexpr} keyword
        \end{itemize}
        
        \item Enumerated constants
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \emph{enum} keyword
        \end{itemize}
        
        \item Defined constants
        \begin{itemize}
            \item $ \# $define
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
```

Comment: Use  `\item \emph{constexpr} keyword`

Comment: SImon is correct. You have the right syntax on lines 6 and 16, but the wrong syntax on line 11.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.